# How to tell if a file handle is a socket?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, posix

I need to log socket usage, and I wrote a LD_PRELOAD library.

The problem is when I override read() and write() than ordinary file operations are get logged too (of course).

So how can I tell ordinary file descriptors and socket descriptors apart?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Call `fstat` on the descriptor and use the [S_ISSOCK](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html) macro on the result.

```
struct stat statbuf;
fstat(fd, &statbuf);
S_ISSOCK(statbuf.st_mode);
```